# Timing nested inside of loops with intervals

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fit a repeating time interval within a window.requestAnimationFrame loop but I'm not sure on how I format the syntax to be able to use something like SetInterval() but that didn't seem to work ... anyway to add setInterval() I couldn't get this to work ... any advice?

```
const renders = function(){
window.requestAnimationFrame(rendres)
setInterval(Dostuff,3000) //right here
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(renders)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const renders = function(){
window.requestAnimationFrame(rendres)
 //do stuff
}
// don't do this
// window.requestAnimationFrame(renders) 

// do this instead
let timer = setInterval(window.requestAnimationFrame(rendres),3000);
```

Then you can use `clearInterval(timer)` if you want to remove the timer.

Comment: oh, so do I need to call setInterval again inside setInterval to use it? I'm confused by your explination

Comment: You declare the rendres function the same way you were before but just change how you call the function. I'll edit to explain better.